# Update all array subobjects relative to their own current value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I want to multiply all nested values by 10.

```js
{
  foos: [
    { val: 1 },
    { val: 10 },
    { val: 5 },
  ]
}
// to
{
  foos: [
    { val: 10 },
    { val: 100 },
    { val: 50 },
  ]
}
```

Since we reuse the existing field values, I assume I will have to use aggregation operators.

Here some attempts:

```
// Does not work, since it it unwinds the values from their parent object.
coll.updateMany({}, [
  {$set: {
    foos: {$map: {
      input: '$foos',
      as: 'foo',
      in: {$multiply: ['$$foo.val', 10]}
    }}
  }}
])
```

```
// MongoServerError: $multiply only supports numeric types, not string
coll.updateMany({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      'foos.val': {$multiply: ['$foos.$.val', 10]}
    }
  }
])
```

Is this possible without fetching the doc, and proceeding to the update with a JS loop?

Something like:

```js
coll.updateMany({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      foos: {
        $map: {
          input: '$foos',
          as: 'foo',
          in: {
            $project: {
              blackMagicToSpreadtheOriginalFoo: '$$foo', // FIXME
              val: { $multiply: ['$$foo.val', 10] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, why do you need: `blackMagicToSpreadtheOriginalFoo: '$$foo', // FIXME`? Why not simply:

```
coll.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      foos: {
        $map: {
          input: "$foos",
          in: {val: {$multiply: ["$$this.val", 10]}}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0QfVeraQMbv)

In case you have other keys inside etch item, just use `$mergeObjects`:

```
coll.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      foos: {
        $map: {
          input: "$foos",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {val: {$multiply: ["$$this.val", 10]}}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - with keys](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iJwtyelhF-Z)

Comment: Thank you. This `$mergeObject` + `$$this` was exactly the black magic I was looking for, and wasn't able to express to google.